# Add a DLL project to a solution VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to add a DLL in an existing solution. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shGA2.png) is what I want it to be, and I saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74aFu.png) in a video, but it doesn't show up. Should I download something from the installer?

Comment: Right click Reference and then select "Add Existing " and browse to dll in the debug project of the new project.  Then add the "using" statement at top of module for the library.

Comment: It's not going to look like your picture though.  That is the picture of a dll being built, you just need to use (import) the dll.  Which will show up as one file under resources.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build one, I don't want to import an external one.

Comment: @Exelendary Make sure you have the *Desktop development with C++* workload installed.